# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_row()

Tags: php, mysql

What can I do to fix my code? I get the following error message when I run the program:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_row() in C:\apache2\Apache2\htdocs\ch\ch32\listing32_2(1).php on line 12

```
<?php

    // Instantiate the mysqli class
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=coorporate", "root", "xxxxxxxx");

    // Assign the employeeID
    $eid = htmlentities($_POST['id']);

    // Execute the stored procedure 
    $result = $db->query("SELECT calculate_bonus('$eid')");

    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    printf("Your bonus is \$%01.2f",$row[0]);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In PDOStatement doesn't exist an fetch_row method - you have to use `PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`

Answer (score 0):

You need [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), there is no `fetch_row()`.

`$row = $result->fetch_row();` should be `$row = $result->fetch();`